# Level of significance for qualitative ordinal data

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, qualitative

I have three sets of qualitative data (n=20). Each has four categories (0,1,2,3) with the data shown in percentage. What would be the best way to show if the differences between them are significant?

Are there other/better ways to compare this kind of data?

Some background: The categories represent the stem length of a leaf with 0=not present, 1=<2cm, 2=5-10cm, 3=>10cm. The data was collected every day for 28 days. The three sets are treatment interval (1 rare, 2 medium, 3 often).

[image: Example of the results]